# Windows 10 license valid for Windows 11?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, windows-11, parallels, arm

I have virtualized Windows 11 ARM using parallels. I have registered it using a valid and original Windows 10 professional license but message activate windows is displayed at the bottom right corner. Isn't Win 10 Pro license valid for Win 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't Win 10 Pro license valid for Win 11?

**A Windows 10 Professional x86/x64 license is not valid for a Windows 11 on ARM installation.**  You will be unable to activate Windows 11 on ARM with the license you have.  In reality the only way to get a valid Windows 11 on ARM license is to purchase an eligible ARM device that comes with Windows 11 on ARM.

Comment: Windows 11 on ARM devices might not exist at this moment, if you have an eligible Windows 10 on ARM device, that can be upgraded to Windows 11 on ARM.

Comment: I virtualized Windows 11 ARM on parallels desktop 17 and not Windows 10 because Windows 10 is not supported by this version of parallels (under macbook with M1 chip). From your comments, I guess and I understand that I cannot activate a Windows 11 ARM even if I use a valid Windows 11 x86/x64 license, right? So the only way would be to get a valid Windows 11 ARM license? or there isn't such kind of licenses for ARM? I have a MacBook Pro M1 with Parallels.

Comment: @Ralph - You would have to purchase a device that already came with Windows 11 on ARM or Windows 10 on ARM as that particular edition is not sold without a compatible device.  I am not exactly sure if it will be possible to run Windows 11 ARM within a VM, since running it on a MacBook Pro M1 with Parallels is technically an unsupported configuration.  Windows 10 on ARM can be ran within the same VM that Windows 11 on ARM runs on by the way.  You are right that you won't be able to run Windows 10 x86/x64 or Windows 11 x64 within a VM on your device.

Comment: FYi Windows 11 on ARM is supported by parallels Desktop 17 as a guest OS. In fact I am virtualizing it on MacBook Pro with M1 chip using Parallels Desktop 17 and it runs very fast. Below link confirms it: https://kb.parallels.com/en/124223

Comment: @Ralph - It's not supported by Microsoft.  It works there is a huge difference, I didn't question the fact it works, I question if Microsoft has provided a legitimate method of purchasing a license to use with on a Parallels Desktop 17 VM on an MacBook Pro M1 device.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I agree. It's not supported by Microsoft.